# APScheduler will not start with Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, apscheduler

This is a section of the code I am trying to run, everything works until I click the menu option "Start". Then the program freezes. If I remove the scheduler part it won't freeze. Can anybody help me what I am doing wrong here. First time I am using Tkinter to make a GUI.

```
def scan():
    alerts.delete(1.0, END)
    alerts.insert(END, "Bot has started with these coins:\n{}".format(symbols))
    sched = BlockingScheduler({"apscheduler.timezone": "UTC",
                               "apscheduler.job_defaults.max_instances": "10"})

    @sched.scheduled_job("cron", minute="*/15", second="1")
    def run_each_15m(interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_15MINUTE):
        # Code to execute

btn = Button(window, text="Clear alerts", command=clear)

btn.grid(column=0, row=1)

# Menu 
menu = Menu(window)

new_item = Menu(menu)

new_item.add_command(label='Start', command=scan)
```

Comment: For some reason changing from BlockingScheduler to BackgroundScheduler has made a ton of difference. At least it is working so far, I'll get back to this topic if an other problem arises.

Comment: I'm hoping you at least read the documentation on why BlockingScheduler is named that way. Its start() method does not return and thus your tkinter event loop will not run.

Comment: Yes I did. I knew it had to do with the scheduler. So I looked into it. First page explained it.

BlockingScheduler: use when the scheduler is the only thing running in your process

BackgroundScheduler: use when you’re not using any of the frameworks below, and want the scheduler to run in the background inside your application

Answer (score 0):

And the problem is solved, changing to BackgroundScheduler did the trick.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
sched = BackgroundScheduler({"apscheduler.timezone": "UTC"})
```